# Determine number of group homomorphisms from dihedral group to cyclic

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism

[image]

Stuck on how to answer this. The most I've done is split it up using the relation, $f(bab) = f(a^{-1}) \Rightarrow f(b) + f(a) +f(b) = -f(a) \Rightarrow f(a) = -f(a)$, for the first one and $f(bab) = f(a^{-1}) \Rightarrow f(b) + f(a) +f(b) = -f(a) \Rightarrow 6 + f(a) = -f(a)$, for the second.

For the first one, my answer is that there are 2 group homomorphisms because $0 = 0$ and $3=-3$ are the only two that satisfy, i.e $im(f) = \{0,3\}$.

But for the second, I'm not getting the right answer. Would appreciate help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fir the second one, we want $f(b)=3$, but what does that tell us about $f(b^2)$? Do you see a problem there?

Comment: Because it's the dihedral group $f(b^2) = 0?$ So only one that would satisfy is the homomorphism with $0$, so only one group homomorphism?

Comment: You're right that $f(b^2)=f(e)$ has to equal $0$, but in $D_8$, if $f(b)=3$, then we have $f(b^2)=6\ne 0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: So that implies we only have the homomorphism with 0 correct since there's no way to have that condition be true?

Comment: Well, the trivial homomorphism doesn't satisfy the given condition, that $f(b)=3$. I think the answer to part (ii) should be $0$. Is that not working?

Comment: Nope, my initial thought was 0 but it says that's incorrect. May just be a bug with the system though, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It looks like a typo. I wonder if they meant to ask about D6 and Z6 again? That makes for a better question, really.